# I want to use tf.Softmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I made the model that predicted the MNIST data using `tf.softmax`.
But it didn't work. the cost was printed as `nan`.
I know it would work to use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` like this

```python
cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis,labels=Y))+ (0.01 * l2reg)
```

I think the code of my cost have problem.
I wonder why the method of using `tf.softmax` doesn't work at a neural nets.
And a adaptation of l2reg is coorect ??
Thanks ~

```python
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np 
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/',one_hot=True)

nb_classes = 10
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,28*28], name='x-input')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,nb_classes], name='y-input')

with tf.name_scope('layer1') as scope:
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28,28*28]),name='weight1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28]),name='bias1')
    layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X,W1)+b1)
    w1_hist = tf.summary.histogram('weight1', W1)
    layer1_hist = tf.summary.histogram('layer1', layer1)

with tf.name_scope('layer2') as scope:
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28,28*28]),name='weight2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28]),name='bias2')
    layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer1,W2)+b2)
    # 1. From TF graph, decide which tensors you want to log
    w2_hist = tf.summary.histogram('weight2', W2)
    layer2_hist = tf.summary.histogram('layer2', layer2)

with tf.name_scope('layer3') as scope:
    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28,nb_classes]),name='weight3')
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nb_classes]),name='bias3')
    logits = tf.matmul(layer2,W3)+b3
    #hypothesis = tf.div(tf.exp(logits),tf.exp(logit,dim)
    hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    w3_hist = tf.summary.histogram('weight3', W3)
    hypothesis_hist = tf.summary.histogram('hypothesis', hypothesis)
with tf.name_scope('cost') as scope:
    # the method of l2reg, when  deep
    l2reg = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W1)) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W2) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W3)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(hypothesis),reduction_indices=1)) + (0.01 * l2reg)
    # cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis,labels=Y))+ (0.01 * l2reg) => this worked very well
    cost_summ = tf.summary.scalar('cost',cost)
with tf.name_scope('train') as scope:
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2).minimize(cost)
predicted = tf.argmax(hypothesis,1)
correction = tf.cast(tf.equal(predicted,tf.argmax(Y,1)),dtype=tf.float32)
Accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correction)

# parameters
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # 2. merge all summaries
    summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    # 3. Create writer and add graph
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/mnist_l2reg_1e-2',sess.graph)
    #writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    # 4. Run summary merge and add_summary
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            s,cost_val,_ = sess.run([summary,cost,train],feed_dict={X:batch_xs,Y:batch_ys})
            writer.add_summary(s, global_step=i)
            avg_cost +=  cost_val / total_batch
        print('{:5} cost: {:.2f}'.format(epoch+1,avg_cost))
    print('Accuracy: ',Accuracy.eval(session=sess,feed_dict={X:mnist.test.images, Y:mnist.test.labels}))
    # Get one and predict
    r = random.randint(0, mnist.test.num_examples - 1)
    print(r, 'test_num: {}, train_num: {}'.format(mnist.test.num_examples,mnist.train.num_examples))
    # numpy.array[something] mean the row of the array
    # notice that if slice like numpy.array[s:s+1], shape will be printed [1,-1]
    print(mnist.test.labels[r],np.shape(mnist.test.labels))
    print('argmax test none axis when array vector{}'.format(tf.argmax(mnist.test.labels[r]).eval(session=sess)))
    print('Label:',sess.run(tf.argmax(mnist.test.labels[r:r+1], 1)))
    print('Prediction:', sess.run(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1),feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images[r:r +1]}))
    plt.imshow(mnist.test.images[r:r+1].reshape(28,28), cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is exactly why `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is so important to use: the numerical instability of the `log` operation itself.

**Explanation**: here you have a rather large network that will end up being very confident in some classifications.  In particular, it will end up assigning extremely **low** probability to some images (say, a picture of a `1`) being of a particular class (say, class `5`).  The `logit` will then be quite negative, and the `tf.nn.softmax` entry for that highly negative logit can be *numerically* zero (not exactly zero, but with finite precision, it will be represented as zero).  Then when you take the `log` to calculate cross entropy yourself, you will get numerical issues, resulting in `nan` values for your cost.  The function `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` deals with that using a trick to avoid `log` and `exp` under/overflow issues.  That trick is sometimes called the *exp-normalize* trick; see [this blog post](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/) (not written by me; I just think it's a clear explanation) for more detail.

In short, use the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and don't try to calculate cross entropy yourself.

Comment: Thanks muskrat !! I could understand this issue.